# Nuxt.js - 'error not defined' when trying to throw 404 in failed await call within asyncData method

Tags: vue.js, try-catch, nuxt.js

Starting to play with Nuxt.js this evening and mock blog data but having an issue with non existing data.

Heres my asyncData method when viewing a single blog post:

```
async asyncData({ params }) {
    try {
        const post = await axios.get(
            `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${params.id}`
        )

        return {
            post: post.data
        }
    } catch (err) {
        error({ statusCode: 404, message: 'Post not found' })
    }
}
```

When visiting a valid ID and a 200 error is returned everything works as expected, but when the endpoint returns a 404 it tells me that 'error is undefined'

I could only find information on doing this error handling using a promise catch method as seen here: https://nuxtjs.org/guide/async-data/#handling-errors

How can I use the error method within the try catch error?

Thanks.

Answer (score 13):

You have to inject the `error` object in your `asyncData` method to use it inside:

```js
async asyncData({ error, params }) {
  // your code
}
```